# java/SQL ORA-00942 table or view does not exist

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have been having a problem with the sql. I have been trying to build a login system that will read a username and password from an oracle DB. When I connect and carry out the command

```
String sql="select * from tutilizadores where username= ? and password= ?";
```

I get the error message ORA-00942. The table has been created under sys. I am confused.

Here is the code that refers to the problem:

```
        String sql="select * from tutilizadores where username= ? and password= ?";
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, USERNAME.getText());
        pst.setString(2, PASSWORD.getText());
        rs=(OracleResultSet)pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O username e password estavam bem");
        //Fecha a janela
        //close();

        //nova janela-Tutilizadores
        Tutilizadores c = new Tutilizadores();
        c.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: First off, NEVER create any user objects under the SYS schema.  Make your own schema.  Who are you logged in as when you execute the query?

Comment: String nameForConnect = "sys as sysdba";
        String pass = "Abcd1234";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:db01";

Comment: sys as sysdba is how I connect

Comment: Did you try `select * from sys.tutilizadores`?

Comment: yes I did. The same message again.

Comment: Try on the sql prompt `select owner,table_name,status from all_tables where tablename like 'tutil%';? Do you use plugable databases?

Answer (score 0):

The number of issues is usually limited to those few options:

1. You are logged in to the wrong database
2. Logged in using the wrong username
3. You are required to qualify the table name with the schema name as in `schema.tutilizadores`. If not sure, then consider schema as the username used to create the table.
4. Somehow you managed to have the table name wrong. Possibly table is case sensitive: if qualified inside double quotes, case will be literally matched, otherwise oracle will assume uppercase.

For verifying what the issue is, consider executing and providing the output of following SQL:

```
SELECT table_name, owner
FROM dba_tables
WHERE lower(table_name) = 'tutilizadores'
```

Comment: its got to be 3. I have covered the other two and I am connected under 2. I only have this db, and I connect for certain.

Comment: so I entered the database as sys as sysdba and did: SQL> select Tables, sys
  2  from tutilizadores
  3  WHERE upper(table_name) = 'tutilizadores';

Comment: getting : ora-00942 : table not seen or not existent

Comment: should i just create another table under a different user and try that ?

Comment: I meant you to try the query literally as is. No replacing or substituting things. That query will need to run as sysdba likely also to have access to that dba view.

Comment: Yes create in your own schema as @OldProgrammer said.

Comment: I have created another user and logged in. All went well. Thank you !!